# Java String object references

Tags: java, object, reference

I would like to clear some doubts on java objects, i have this code:

```
public class Strut
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s=new String("wooo!");
        String t=s;
        System.out.println(s+","+t);
        t="blaaaah";
        System.out.println(s+","+t);
    }
}
```

If i got it right object are always allocated on the heap, because java doesn't allocate objects on the stack by design.
so the variable s and t are merely references to the same object in the code that i wrote right?
so when i print s and t for the first time i expect the same result and it's fine.
but after i modify t and print the strings again they are different,
shouldn't s have become blaaaah since t and s are references to the same object?
thanks

Comment: `t` now refers to a different object.

Comment: you mean that when i wrote="blaaaah" it allocated a new object and connected t to it insted of modifying the already existing one?
also may i know why have i been downvoted?

Comment: That's correct.  `=` doesn't modify objects.  I don't know why you were downvoted...

Comment: If you understand pointers in C, it is easy to understand this. `p` and `s` are simply pointers and when you **point** `p` to a different object, the value of the pointer `p` (memory address of pointee) is now different from the value of `s`. Also from the way you have stated your question, it seems like you're implying that Java does not use the stack for storage. It does, and infact that line `t="blaaaah";` is probably stack allocated

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Java-allow-stack-allocated-objects
so the people in this forum are wrong?

Comment: `t` is not an object.  It is a reference to an object.  The reference lives on the stack.  The object lives on the heap.

Comment: You're modifying `t` (the variable), not the object that `t` refers to (which happens to be impossible in the case of `String`).

Answer (score -1):

That can be answered in one phrase: Strings are immutable.
So yes, everytime you use quotation marks, you are in fact, making a new String object. Thats's why instead of doing:

```
String s=new String("wooo!");
```

You could just do:

```
String s = "wooo!";
```

And it would be the same.
PS.:Immutable means each String object will ever have the same value, until it's destroyed, if a String refference changes value, you can know for sure that it is refferencing a different object.

Comment: thanks, so can you confirm that in java objects are always allocated on the heap and never on the stack?

Comment: This is not because of String immutability.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Right.  Strings ARE immutable, but it would be the same with any other object.  (But I guess the fact that Strings are immutable hammers home the point that the code *can't* be modifying them.)

Comment: @GiannandreaVicidomini From your link, "You will note that the definition of the heap does not actually specify any particular data structure (such as an actual heap, for example), which means that the JVM could theoretically choose to allocate objects on the program stack (i.e. the stack that an assembly program has direct access to via ss:bp, push/pop, etc.) and consider that part of its “heap”."  But, why do you care where they are allocated?

Comment: i want to have as few doubts as possible.